# Android: saerchable.xml and searchSuggestThreshold parameter

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I have a search function in my project. In the searchable.xml, i would like to limit the search only when user types at least 3 characters.

This can be done with  android:searchSuggestThreshold="3" but in my case, nothing happens, the user can still perform a search when he types on or more characters.

Here is my searchable.xml:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/Label"
    android:hint="@string/Hint"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="3"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"/>
```

Here is the 2 search activityes from the Manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".Search"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
          <intent-filter>   
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>   
        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".SearchInterface"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
         <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".Search" />
         </activity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before answer your question there is one thing you have to change in the AndroidManifest.

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".Search" />
```

have to be between `<application></application>` tags but not inside `<activity></activity>` ones. Because it declares the default activity to call when a Search intent is fired.
After that try if the android:searchSuggestThreshold now works. What you can do as a workaround is in the SearchHelper you are using (the class that manage sql queries) you recieve the search input from the user as the parameter so you can put a simple if. Like this:

```
public static Cursor getAutoCompleteCursor(String s) {
    Cursor cursor;
    if (s != null && s.length() > 2)
        cursor = searchAutoComplete(s);
    else
        cursor = null;
    return cursor;
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Any doubt just let me know!

Comment: Hi @rallat, thank you for your answer. I tryed the first solution and nothing changed. If you take a look to this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html the metadata is in the activity tag and not in the application tag.

Comment: for the second solution, I think this is not really possible because when the user types the search button, the search activity is closed and a new one is opened where i am doing all the querryes and display the results. So, I need to check the input lenght when the user clicks the search button

Comment: writing the metadata between the application tags means that searchable activity can invoke search from the whole app. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Comment: So know I understand the problem you are using this android:searchSuggestThreshold="3" but you are not using Suggestion right? That's why the threshold doesn't work. Please take a look at the dictionary example with the suggestion and you will understand how to create the suggestion that checks the android:searchSuggestThreshold parameter